# Agora.io client joining the channel is not working properly in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, agora.io

```
created() {
    let $ = this;
    // init AgoraRTC local client
    const config = {
        mode: "rtc",
        codec:"h264",
        areaCode: [AgoraRTC.AREAS.GLOBAL]
    };
    $.client = AgoraRTC.createClient(config);
    $.client.init($.appId, () => {
      console.log("AgoraRTC client initialized");
      $.subscribeStreamEvents();
      $.client.join($.appId, $.channel, $.uid, function(uid) {
        console.log("User " + uid + " join channel successfully");
        console.log("At " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
        // create local stream
        // It is not recommended to setState in function addStream
        $.localStream = this.streamInit(uid, $.attendeeMode, $.videoProfile);
        $.localStream.init(
          () => {
            if ($.attendeeMode !== "audience") {
              $.addStream($.localStream, true);
              $.client.publish($.localStream, err => {
                console.log("Publish local stream error: " + err);
              });
            }
            $.readyState = true;
          },
          err => {
            console.log("getUserMedia failed", err);
            $.readyState = true;
          }
        );
      },function(err) {
        console.error("client join failed", err);
      });//end join
    });//end init
  },
```

Agora installed using npm

```
 npm i agora-rtc-sdk
```

"agora-rtc-sdk": "^3.1.2",
"vue": "^2.5.17",
"vuetify": "^2.2.9"

in the above code

```
$.client.join($.appId, $.channel, $.uid, function(uid) {
```

this line keep joining but did not succeed and also do not gives failure error. it just keep trying to connect to server.

**here is the screenshot of errors/warnings**
[image]

**Please help me I'm stuck on it for 2 days**
And Sorry for bad english

Comment: Were you able to fix this? What happens when you don't specify area code?

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation is a bit tricky on this one. The `client.join()` function accepts 4 arguments as follows:

```
client.join(APPID, CHANNEL, TOKEN(can be null), UID(optional), function(uid){
  // uid returned
})
```

So update your code to read:

```
$.client.join($.appId, $.channel, null, function(uid) {
```

I'm actually using the AgoraWebSDK NG for my VueJS project. You can checkout the guide to migration here: https://agoraio-community.github.io/AgoraWebSDK-NG/docs/en/migration_guide.